# Empty black space at the bottom of Phonegap / cordova android app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am building Android app using Phonegap Build, but am getting app with empty black area slightly more than size of navigation bar where navigation bar is supposed to be present.

[image: App in Portrait mode]
[image: App in Landscape mode]

My config.xml is below

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" source="npm" spec="~2.3.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />

<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <supports-screens 
        android:xlargeScreens="true" 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" ></activity>
    </application>
</gap:config-file>
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#58D4C9" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />

<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

I have tried `preference FullScreen` and most of the plugins related to screen, immersive view and navigation bar but without any luck. Can anybody knows whats missing?

Duplicate: [Cordova Fullscreen black bars on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675408/cordova-fullscreen-black-bars-on-android)